# How to treat input field value as a number?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this very basic calculator:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form">
            <input type="text" name="num1" />
            <input type="text" name="num2" />
            <input type="text" name="res" />
            <input type="button" value="+" onclick="form.res.value = form.num1.value + form.num2.value" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But it treats `form.num1.value` and `form.num2.value` as string and because of it the result  is the concatenation of these values instead of addition.

How to treat them as numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap each value in a `parseInt(value, 10)` or `parseFloat(value)`.

Comment: Thanks. Is the default base `10`?

Comment: @user1798362 Yes, the default is base 10, however older browsers will user base 8 if the string begins with `"0"`.

Comment: @bfavaretto when did they make that breaking change?

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way is the [unary plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120802/explain-var-and-var-unary-operator-in-javascript), which converts to Number:

```
+form.num1.value + +form.num2.value
```

Note: it will return `NaN` for mixed inputs like "10 potatoes". To avoid that, you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert them to number like this:

```
onclick="Numberform.res.value = Number(form.num1.value) + Number(form.num2.value)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert them to numbers with the `+` operator or `parseFloat`.