# + unary operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

i have read this topic already :
[Explain +var and -var unary operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120802/explain-var-and-var-unary-operator-in-javascript)

but i still can't understand this simple code :

```
var a = 3;
console.log(-a);  // -3
console.log(+a);  //  3
a = -a;
console.log(a);  // -3
console.log(+a);  // -3
```

*"The unary negation operator precedes its operand and negates it."*

*"The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a number, if it isn't already."*

but i still can't figure why console.log(+a) return 3 the first time.

Comment: your third `console.log` outputs `3` and not `-3`.

Comment: @X.L.Ant you are right i have edit my post. thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but i still can't figure why console.log(+a) return 3 the first time.

The value of `a` is `3` at that point.

The previous line, `-a`, takes the *value of `a`*, negates it and passes it to `console.log`. It **doesn't** assign the changed value back to `a`.

Comment: Thanks Quentin so ++ and + doesn't behave the same way in js. Because if i make var a = 0; console.log(++a); // 1 console.log(--a); // 0. so in that case having the operator before the operand does modify the variable. In other word when the operator ++ is before it modify the variable, but the when the operator + is before it doesn't modify it ? Js is tricky ... :)

Comment: `++a` is short for `a = a+1`

Comment: Well, yes. Different operators do different things.

Comment: `+a` and `++a` are totally different.

Comment: thanks guys for your answers. and forgive the noobish question.