# How to sum json array key's value if it has one common key

Tags: javascript

I have a json object like this. 
Each of this json object can have common `Product` name, for example `orgs[0]` & `orgs[3]` have same product name.

```
"orgs":
    [{
    "Budget Actual Consumption": "12.00",
    "Budget Planned Consumption": "50.00",
    "Product": "Loyalty CO-brand"

}, {
    "Budget Actual Consumption": "11.00",
    "Budget Planned Consumption": "60.00",
    "Product": "Loaylty Rebates"
}, {
    "Budget Actual Consumption": "10.00",
    "Budget Planned Consumption": "7.00",
    "Product": "Loaylty Rebates"
}, {

    "Budget Actual Consumption": "9.00",
    "Budget Planned Consumption": "8.00",
    "Product": "Loyalty CO-brand"
}]
```

Is it possible to create a new array in such a way that it will have unique multiple object each of which have unique product name & other key will be summed up

For example

```
var someArray = [{
   name:"Loyalty CO-brand",
   bac:"21" //12+9
   pac:"58" //50+8
},{
  name:"Loaylty Rebates",
   bac:"21" //10+11
   pac:"67" //60+7 

}]
```

I tried by first creating an array of unique `Product`,then using `forEach` twice one inside another. But I could not successfully complete that as I am not sure how will I add up the other keys value when there is a matching `Products`

Comment: do you need the spaces behind the number in the strings?

Comment: No i dont need those space, I have edited it

Comment: please, show us your code and what's not working in it

Comment: I think you have some typos in your desired result.. Both are "Loyalty CO-brand", one should probably be "Loyalty Rebates". And also, I don't think `60+7 = 58`, and `50+8 = 67`.

Comment: @Arg0n thanks yes that was a typo, I have updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the result should be grouped by `Product`, the you could use an object as hash table for the objects of the result array.

When you omit the requirement of getting strings instead of numbers, the algorithm would be shorter.

```js
var data = { "orgs": [{ "Budget Actual Consumption": "12.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "50.00 ", "Product": "Loyalty CO-brand" }, { "Budget Actual Consumption": "11.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "60.00 ", "Product": "Loaylty Rebates" }, { "Budget Actual Consumption": "10.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "7.00 ", "Product": "Loaylty Rebates" }, { "Budget Actual Consumption": "9.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "8.00 ", "Product": "Loyalty CO-brand" }] },
    grouped = [];

data.orgs.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.Product]) {
        this[a.Product] = { name: a.Product, bac: '0', pac: '0' };
        grouped.push(this[a.Product]);
    }
    this[a.Product].bac = (+this[a.Product].bac + +a['Budget Actual Consumption']).toString();
    this[a.Product].pac = (+this[a.Product].bac + +a['Budget Planned Consumption']).toString();

}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: What do the `+`  bits before the 2 values ( `+this[a.Product].bac + +a['Budget Actual Consumption']` ) do in these lines? Thanks.

Comment: its an type cast to number.

Comment: Thanks. Read some more about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120802/explain-var-and-var-unary-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @NinaScholz Maybe `bac` and `pac` souldn't be string then your to string and reassignments would be unnecessary. BTW that could happen with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @mortezaT, the requirement shows strings, so i do strings. `JSON.stringify` does not convert numbers to string, instead it put the whole object into a string.

Answer (score 4):

The solution using `Array.forEach` function:

```
var org = { "orgs": [{ "Budget Actual Consumption": "12.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "50.00 ", "Product": "Loyalty CO-brand" }, { "Budget Actual Consumption": "11.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "60.00 ", "Product": "Loaylty Rebates" }, { "Budget Actual Consumption": "10.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "7.00 ", "Product": "Loaylty Rebates" }, { "Budget Actual Consumption": "9.00 ", "Budget Planned Consumption": "8.00 ", "Product": "Loyalty CO-brand" }] },
    newArr = [], bac = 'Budget Actual Consumption', pac = 'Budget Planned Consumption';

org.orgs.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!this[o.Product]) {
        this[o.Product] = {name: o.Product, bac: +o[bac], pac: +o[pac]};
        newArr.push(this[o.Product]);
    } else {
        this[o.Product]['bac'] += +o[bac];
        this[o.Product]['pac'] += +o[pac];
    }                
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Loyalty CO-brand",
        "bac": 21,
        "pac": 58
    },
    {
        "name": "Loaylty Rebates",
        "bac": 21,
        "pac": 67
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice solution with [Underscore groupBy](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy)

http://codepen.io/therealplato/pen/KMWPPN

```
//foo = {"orgs":[...]}
console.log(foo);
grouped = _.groupBy(foo.orgs, grouper);
console.log(grouped);
function grouper(item) {
  return item["Product"];
}
```

[image: example output of _groupBy]

Comment: Now that you have one array per type, your next step is to use _.map() to calculate the stats for that particular type