# How can '+myVar;' be a valid syntax

Tags: javascript

I just got a bug that took some of my time to spot my searching filters weren't working because of the following code :

```
queryObject.search='valid==true';+searchQuery;
```

The good syntax is to mive the ';' in the string :

```
queryObject.search='valid==true;'+searchQuery;
```

The reasn why i didn't spot that is because the earlier line of code didn't triggered any javascript console error. So it seems it's a valid syntax.

So here is my question, how can this be a valid syntax ?

Comment: It's implicit numeric conversion. `-variable` is an implicit `variable *= -1`

Comment: strange i did search for '+myVar' on google but i didn't get that. Sorry for the dup

Comment: @Walfrat Searchs on operators in programming are always hard until you just look at the list of operators in a good documentation (the MDN is the best one for JS).

Comment: In fairness, google isn't really good on searching programm-y things like `+word` as it will search for `word`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret will remeber this, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+something` is an expression using the [plus unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()).

Its general purpose is to convert a value, for example a string, to a number.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is unary operator, which tries to get numeric value from variable.

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120802/explain-var-and-var-unary-operator-in-javascript) about it.