# Why the plus sign in the expression logical expression `product.id === +id;`?

Tags: javascript

Looking at a javascript expression:

```
return product.id === +id;
```

I've never seen a `+` sign in front of a variable like this before...Thoughts?

Comment: look at type coercion in javascript - or even unary `+`

Comment: Ah so the `+` turns the type of `id` into the type of `product.id`?

Comment: No, it turns it into a number regardless of what `product.id` is.

Comment: It's basically a silly way to "force" JS to do the right thing. Whoever wrote this is using `===` to make sure that JS does **not** use coercion, and then they immediately force it to coerce the value of `id` to a number using a coercive expression. The proper intentful code equivalent would be `product.id === parseInt(id, 10);`

Comment: actually you'd parseFloat not parseInt to be (almost) equivalent, as unary + does not make an integer, it makes a Number - except `+"123bob" === NaN` and `pareFloat("123bob") === 123` - so it's not `equivalent` it's `similar but not the same`

Comment: parseFloat only makes sense in a context where product identifiers use fractional values. That's almost never, so: the obvious choice here is `parseInt(id, 10)`, but depending on context, it _could_ be `parseFloat(id)`, too.

Comment: compare `123 === +"123.45"` with `123 === parseInt("123.45", 10)` or `123.45 === +"123.45"` with `123.45 === parseInt("123.45", 10)` ... now, tell me which one is correct? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converts a variable to a Number, if success: +id equals Number(id). If the conversion fails, it will return NaN

Answer (score 1):

The plus sign in front of your variable is called a [Unary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) and it's used to convert a variable into a number. If the value is numeric, the result of the operation will be a number, otherwise `NaN`.

You can roughly equate the `+` operator's functionality to [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). However, note that the former can only parse a numeric string, while the latter can extract the numeric value even if it's followed by another one that's not.

**Example:**

```js
var a = "0x";

console.log("Unary Operator:", +a);
console.log("parseFloat:", parseFloat(a, 16));
```

---

In your particular case, it's used to make sure that, if turned into a number, the `id` is strictly equal to `product.id`. If `id` isn't numeric the function will return `false`, because `product.id != NaN`, even if `product.id` itself equals `NaN`.

**Example:**

```js
var
  id1 = 13,
  id2 = "13",
  id3 = "a13";

console.log("number:", id1);
console.log("numeric string:", +id2);
console.log("non-numeric string:", +id3);
console.log("NaN !== NaN:", +id3 !== +id3);
```

**Just a Note:**

Despite `NaN` literally meaning `"Not a Number"`, if you use `typeof NaN` the result will be `"number"`, even though `NaN` isn't a number in the mathematical sense of the word.

---

**Relevant Threads:**

- [What is the purpose of a plus symbol before a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6682997/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-plus-symbol-before-a-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Explain +var and -var unary operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120802/explain-var-and-var-unary-operator-in-javascript)
- [What's the significant use of unary plus and minus operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450076/whats-the-significant-use-of-unary-plus-and-minus-operators)